# Accessing properties when looping through an array of type any in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

data is an array of type Object...

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'test 2'
}
```

How can I access element.id when doing a forEach on data? In the below example it doesn't like element.id. It says Property 'id' does not exist on type Object.

```
// Need to make sure this code completes
data.forEach(element => {
    this.myservice.delete(element.id).subscribe();
});
```

Comment: What doesn't it like, actual errors are better than vague statements, also what type is `data` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir data is an array of type Object. The error is: Property 'id' does not exist on type Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a type of `any`

```
data.forEach(element => {
    this.myservice.delete((element as any).id).subscribe();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To type an object whose structure is not fully known or which you want to access in a type unsafe way you should use `any`.

```
declare var data: any[];
data.forEach(element => {
    this.myservice.delete(element.id).subscribe();
});
```

However in this case the structure is known and is pretty simple, I would actually use a proper type:

```
declare var data: Array<{ id: number, name: string}>;
data.forEach(element => {
    this.myservice.delete(element.id).subscribe();
});
```

Comment: In my case I can't declare data. It is a response from an observable subscription. So I am inside of an observable using res => res.data. I believe I need to use map, but am unsure of how.

Comment: sure you can, just do `let data: Array<{ id: number, name: string}> = res.data` or `(res.data as any[]).forEach(..)`. How are you creating the observable ? It might be possible to pass in a type argument to the call creating the observable to tell it the type of `data`. Postin a more complete example will get better answeres